# How does social security in Iran work and how good are the services it provides?

Tags: iran, middle-east, social-security

I read that Iran provides every citizen with social security covering unemployment, old age, disability, accidents, calamities, health and medical treatment and care services that is required by the Iranian Constitution. How exactly does this social security system work though and how much help does it actually provide the Iranian citizens that depend on it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Healthcare_in_Iran https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Iran#Social_security etc.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: where did you read that? I rather had the impression that the economy in Iran is not doing very well.